# Execução de aplicação console (C#) em outra máquina Windows

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicação console, onde leio um arquivo .txt e realizo umas rotinas de *INSERT* a minha base de dados.

A aplicação executando na minha máquina funciona normal, mas ao executar meu .exe em outra máquina, a mesma abre o console e fecha de imediato.

Obs: todas as máquinas possuem a versão 3.1 do .NET core

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

consoleApp1.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
   <ApplicationIcon>refresh_106672.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;osx.10.12-x64;debian.8-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.2" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Você verificou se os registros foram gravados? A aplicação console fecha após a execução, a menos que você informe algum comando para aguardar uma ação. [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5891612/1697470) tem um exemplo de como usar o ESC para fechar applicação.

Comment: Verifique se máquina tem o dotnet hosting: https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/beca42b0-54a8-4364-86b8-a3d88003fbb7/592e0eec1e5e53f78d9647f7112cc743/dotnet-hosting-3.1.9-win.exe

Comment: Crie um arquivo de log, a cada passo. Com isso vai descobrir onde esta o problema.

Comment: Veja no Event Viewer qual é exatamente o erro